# WCF Datacontract for XML deeper that a single layer

Tags: wcf, datacontract

Sorry for a very simple question, I can't seem to find an answer.  I'm trying to write a datacontract for a WCF service to receive the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CachedAwiData QReference="3" QAttempt="0" QReservation="{D6154D1C-6D42-4AA5-9FAC-217B2F9FE096}">
                <CachedAwiDataRecord>
                                <CustRef><![CDATA[1]]></CustRef>
                                <Details><![CDATA[Hello World]]></Details>
                                <PrefDay><![CDATA[Monday]]></PrefDay>
                                <PrefTime><![CDATA[8.00am - 9.00am]]></PrefTime>
                                <Priority><![CDATA[Urgent]]></Priority>
                                <Trade><![CDATA[Plasterer]]></Trade>
                </CachedAwiDataRecord>
</CachedAwiData>
```

so far I have tried a couple of things and got as far as:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class CachedAwiData
{

}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class CachedAwiDataRecord : CachedAwiData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CustRef { get; set; }
}
```

I've got as far as getting a response that seems to get a null value for CustRef:

```
<ResponseData xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><CustRef i:nil="true" /></ResponseData>
```

I'm assuming its to do with my DataContract but perhaps I'm missing something here.  Any clues greatly appreciated or am I best just going back to XML Serializer?

Comment: It seems you want to customize your serialized message, but using DataContract  you couldn't customize a lot. Suggest you could use xmlSerizlizer [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class)  or try Message contract [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts)

Comment: Hi Ackelry, thanks for the reply. Its probably added confusion that I'm returning it as xml, the main thing I am trying to do at the moment is read in the element values passed to the wcf service as part of a http post request.  What I am failing to understand is how to write the DataContract to deserialize xml where I need to delve from a Root Element to a Child element that contains the actual data elements. I've already found I can't easily access the Attributes on the Root Element which may change the way I approach this anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the inheritance is right. I don't use DataContracts much but I think you need something like

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class CachedAwiData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public CachedAwiDataRecord DataRecord;
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class CachedAwiDataRecord 
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string CustRef { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi spodger,  Thanks for the answer, I was just writing my own answer as I realised after a coffee or two I had asked the question wrong.  It is a nested type I'm trying to access and realised my inheritance was wrong, Your code is an exact replica of what I have now tested and got the right result.  If I edit my question I would find there is a near duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990086/wcf-how-to-construct-datacontracts-for-a-type-within-a-type    Full Marks for the answer.